# what's wrong with my XML schema?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

This is the schema in `my.xsd`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
  xmlns:p='some-namespace' targetNamespace='some-namespace'>
  <xs:element name='root' type='p:main'/>
  <xs:complexType name='main'>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='alpha' type='xs:string' />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the XML document I'm validating against it:

```
<root xmlns='some-namespace' 
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
  xsi:schemaLocation='some-namespace my.xsd'>
  <alpha>xxx</alpha>
</root>
```

SAX parser says:

```
"Invalid content was found starting with element 'alpha'. One of 
'{alpha}' is expected."
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add

```
elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

in your schema definition. It would also be a good idea not to use relative namespace, i.e. use something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:p="http://some-namespace" targetNamespace="http://some-namespace"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
```